# My JavaScript files appears empty in the iMacros Editor

Tags: javascript, utf-8, imacros

I have a tricky problem with iMacros. I write them using Atom which saves files in us-ascii. When I copy the file in my macro directory and try to update it with the iMacro editor, it appears empty. I'm using Firefox and I am on OS X Mavericks.

I first thought, it was an encoding problem coming from Atom, but it's not. You can add [as explained in this thread](https://discuss.atom.io/t/ask-atom-to-save-file-in-utf8-not-us-ascii/12194/6) the ʤ character in the file and run `file -I myFile.js`. It will display this time `charset=utf-8`. Reopen the file with iMacros. It will still appear empty.

I don't really know what hack I can do, because I don't want to copy/paste my macros in the editor each time I make a change. I have more than a 100 files.

Comment: Do something with user permisions or file encoding. Then it will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bom issue. Here is what you need to do to solve this problem.

### 1. Create a new script to automatically add bom to an UTF-8 file.

```
nano add_bom.sh
```

### 2. Copy the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# add_bom.sh

FILE=$1

check() {
  if (( e = "$1" )); then
    echo "ERROR: $ACTION failed!!"
    exit $e
  else
    echo "INFO: $ACTION Success!!"
  fi
}

set_bom() {
    ACTION="Setting utf-8 BOM"
    # Detect if BOM already exists
    BOM=`sed -n '1{/^\xEF\xBB\xBF/p}' $FILE`
    if [ -z $BOM ]; then
        [ -f "$FILE" ] && /usr/bin/vim -e -s +"set bomb|set encoding=utf-8|wq" $FILE
        check $?
    fi
}

set_bom
```

### 3. Run the script.

```
sh ./add_bom.sh /path/to/file
```

### 4. Test the file via xxd, if the mark is present, the first line should output as below:

```
$ xxd </path/to/file>
0000000: efbb bf...
```